# Extend Wifi signal as an access point with a Router TP Link wired

Tags: wireless-networking

I have two routers a `Netgear` `DGND3700V2` and  a `TP Link` `TL-WR1043ND v4 00000000`

I want to extend the Wifi Signal in a way that if I am walking around I don't have to change my Wifi network. I can not use the repeater function, in a WiFi mode, because the routers positions don't allow this, they must be wired.

Is it posible to extend the WiFi network with both routers wired?

Comment: You can extend the wifi, using the wire, as you desire, if you configure both devices to use the same configuration (SSID name, passphrase etc.). the only problem you may notice is when you are roaming between the networks. They won't have any "hand-over" capability so you will inevitably notice that you will need to re-connect to the wireless when you go out of range of one and in-range of the next. Business-grade equipment (such as Ubiquiti, Cisco, DrayTek etc.) have functionality that provides seamless roaming of devices between access points and continuous connectivity.

Comment: You can add a simple Ubiquiti Lite access point off an Ethernet cable and it is an extension of your wireless. You can walk around and not change networks. Signal strength is high because it is not a repeater. I have done that here to put wireless upstairs